# How can I pass Multiple addresses in Move command

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli, movecmd

I have to pass multiple addresses in move command but I am not able to pass as it is not accepting more than one wallet address Is there is any another way to move the balance to multiple addresses.

Answer (score -1):

You can't pass multiple addresses to Move commands, also `move` will be removed in a later version of Bitcoin Core.

Please consider using `sendtoaddress` instead

Comment: No, don't use `sendtoaddress`. `move` is just moving internal bean counters in the wallet around. There is no equivalent for it. The correct advise is to first look whether you need move and accounts at all (hint: they're almost certainly not what you think they are), and then determine the correct equivalent. Perhaps that means using multiple separate wallets, or having your own application keep track of different users' balances.